# limit $lookup results to 1 document after sorting in Moongose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My rentals schema:

```
var rentals = [{
    deviceId: 1,
    start_date: ISODate("2018-05-10T10:11:23.143Z") ,
    end_date: ISODate("2018-07-11T12:19:53.143Z")
},{
...
}]
```

My readings schema:

```
[{
    deviceId: 1,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-05-11T10:11:23.143Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-03-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
    deviceId: 2,
    timestamp: ISODate("2018-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
    data: 'wathever'
},{
...
}]
```

I need to join both collections with readings using $lookup but for each rental (deviceId) I just need to get one reading, the one with higher timestamp (latest). There are N readings for each rental in the DB.

My approach:

```
Rental.aggregate([
      { "$match": { 
            clientId : ObjectId(req.params.clientId)
      }},    
      {  
          $lookup:{  
             from:"readings",
             localField:"deviceId",
             foreignField:"deviceId",
             let: { timestamp: "$timestamp"},
             pipeline: [
                 { $sort: { "$$timestamp": -1}},
                 { $limit : 1 },
             ],
             as:"lastReading"
          }
       },
       { $unwind: "$lastReading" },


    ], function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

I am getting an error:

```
(node:1392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: arguments to $l
ookup must be strings, let: { time: "$time" } is type object
```

The time field in the readings schema is Date type.
There must be something I am not doing it right...

Comment: Newer lookup syntax is available from 3.6. It looks you are lower version of mongo. Run db.version() to check your version on shell.

Comment: @Veeram I am in 3.4.2...is there anything I can do to get what I want in 3.4.2?

Comment: It would be better if you upgrade your mongodb version to get faster result and customized query because new `$lookup` syntax `$limit` the fields inside the pipeline itself which makes execution faster

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thanks, I think I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation which is post processing the joined data.

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get all readings based on device id followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) / [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to sort the readings on timestamp in desc.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on _id to collect the last reading from each rental.

Something like

```
Rental.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"clientId":ObjectId(req.params.clientId)}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"readings",
    "localField":"deviceId",
    "foreignField":"deviceId",
    "as":"readings"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$readings"},
  {"$sort":{"readings.timestamp":-1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","lastReading":{"$first":"$readings"}}}
])
```